# VBA - Excel - Display one section of sheet using different column widths

Tags: vba, excel

I couldn't figure out how to word the question, so please comment if you have a better wording.

I am creating a report the has multiple sections, all displayed on one sheet. One of the sections need to be displayed at equal column widths, while the rest of the report has varying column widths. What I would like to do is display this section as some sort of chart/table that will display as if it was part of a continuous report. Should I be using listboxes or is there a better option?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's no support for one column having a variable width.  Best you can do is try to fake it by merging cells, or maybe use the Camera tool to overlay a linked image from another sheet.

Comment: I do this all the time to create reports. And like @TimWilliams said The best way to handle the situation is to start with the gettings the total width you want, then work from the most populated rows (have to most used columns), then next most populated row and so on merging cells when needed subsequent rows' cells to retain the first rows widths. Its not fun or easy but that gets the best and most usable presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but from what I do understand, maybe what you could do is put the part with the fixed column widths on another part of your sheet and then:

- Copy it
- Go to where you want it in the report and `Paste Special` > `Linked Picture (I)`

I think that would give you what you're looking to accomplish, otherwise, please clarify a bit more...

Comment: I would like the data to be actual numbers, so a picture won't work. I'm think more like embedding on sheet into another, and filling the embedded sheet with VBA. I'm just not sure how to go about embedding it.

Comment: No.. It does embed the numbers (it simply pastes the cells there as an over-lay) and when you change the other part of the sheet, it automatically updates the "picture"...

Comment: If I'm creating a remote range and linking, then I can use a ListBox. I was hoping not to need another range, and to just fill a embedded "Table" with data.